# Animation on android make device to lag

Tags: android, animation, device, lag

I need some information why my animation are making devices to lag. The current problem is seen in Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4'', but in all devices the are slight lags, kaing writing on keyboard heavy. Thank you for your cooperation !!! :)

PS: Thanks Mikael :). Here is some code. Its complicated animation and it contains several parts very similar to this one with combine animation of several views.

CODE :

```
    mTriangleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mLearnMore = (LinearLayout) ((LoginActivity) context)
                    .findViewById(R.id.learn_more);

            if (mAccNameEmail.isShown()) {
                // Slider
                if (BookshelfApp.isTablet(context)) {

                    if(getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                        mDeseretLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mSquigle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mBorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN, 0);

                    }

                    view.animate().translationX(0);
                    view.animate().setDuration(500);
                    mLearnMore.animate().translationX(0);
                    mLearnMore.animate().setDuration(500);
                    mLearnMore.animate().setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                            mLearnMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

                    //XXX
                } else if (!BookshelfApp.isTablet(context)) {
                    mCreateAccFragment.animate().translationY(0);
                    mDeseretLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mSquigle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mBorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                mTextHint1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTextHint2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTriangleButton.animate().rotation(0);
                mTriangleButton.animate().setDuration(500);
                mAccPasswords.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAccNameEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSignUpButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.sign_up_shape));
                mSignUpButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.orange));
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSignInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mForgotPasswordView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCreateAccountQuestion
                        .setText(R.string.acc_question_welcome);
                mCreateAccountWord.setText(R.string.acc_welcome);
                mHaveAccountButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // Slider
                if (BookshelfApp.isTablet(context)) {

                    if(getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                        mDeseretLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mSquigle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mBorder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN, 0);

                    }

                    view.animate().translationX(-view.getWidth() / 4);
                    view.animate().setDuration(500);
                    mLearnMore.animate().translationX(view.getWidth() / 2);
                    mLearnMore.animate().setDuration(500);
                    mLearnMore.animate().setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            mLearnMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                }
                //XXX
                else if (!BookshelfApp.isTablet(context)) {
                    mDeseretLogo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSquigle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mBorder.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                mTextHint1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mTextHint2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSignInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mForgotPasswordView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mTriangleButton.animate().rotation(180);
                mTriangleButton.animate().setDuration(300);
                mAccPasswords.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAccNameEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSignUpButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.sign_in_shape));
                mSignUpButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.white));
                mCreateAccountQuestion.setText(R.string.acc_question);
                mCreateAccountWord.setText(R.string.acc_done);
                mHaveAccountButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are likely not being efficient with your code but given that there is no code in your question it's impossible to know for sure. Perhaps one suggestion is to take a computer science class that explains the inner workings of a computer.

Comment: I add some code, Mikael. Thanks for the support hope the example code will help :) !